# How to return extended class like a generic class?

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I have three classes `AdminAccount`, `CustomerAccount`, `ConfectionerAccount` that are extended from `Account`. In the method `findByUsername(String username)` I want to check these three classes and return the one that is not NULL.

```
    public <R extends Account> R findByUsername(String username) {
        AdminAccount adminAccount = adminAccountDao.findByUsername(username).orElse(null);
        CustomerAccount customerAccount = customerAccountDao.findByUsername(username).orElse(null);
        ConfectionerAccount confectionerAccount = confectionerAccountDao.findByUsername(username).orElse(null);
        return Stream.of(adminAccount, customerAccount, confectionerAccount).filter(Objects::nonNull).findFirst().get();
    }
```

But when I try to return, I get

```
Required type: R
Provided: Account
```

Can you explain, please, where is my mistake? How to return a concrete class, like `AdminAccount`, `CustomerAccount` or `ConfectionerAccount`?

Answer (score 0):

This is a misuse of generics. Generic type parameters are determined by the caller, not by the callee, so `findByUsername` don't get to decide what `R` is, based on which one of those accounts is null. The caller should be able to decide what `R` is, i.e. I can do:

```
class Foo extends Account {}

...

Foo foo = findByUsername("Sweeper");
```

and you must be able to give me a `Foo`.

Clearly, `findByUsername` isn't capable of doing that, so it shouldn't be generic.

You should just return an `Account` here:

```
public Account findByUsername(String username) {
```

Now the caller can't choose which kind of account it wants from `findByUsername`, which makes total sense, because the caller, in general, can't "see" how `findByUsername` works and work out what kind of account it will return for a given username.